# How to access source code of a file from a Visual Studio Extension

Tags: visual-studio, vsix

I am trying to write a Microsoft Visual Studio extension that analyzes the code and notifies the user of each function's cyclomatic complexity score. I was accessing code for analysis through an IWpfTextView, however now I am noticing that IWpfTextView.TextViewLines only contains the lines of code that are visible on the screen. I need to be able to access the all the code and not just visible code in order to calculate cyclomatic complexity. Does anybody know how I could access all of the code? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Using the code model of the automation model (EnvDTE) you would use EnvDTE.Project.CodeModel or EnvDTE.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel. See:

[HOWTO: Get an EnvDTE.DTE instance from a Visual Studio package.](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/packages/)

[HOWTO: Navigate the code elements of a file from a Visual Studio .NET macro or add-in.](http://www.visualstudioextensibility.com/articles/add-ins/)

Each EnvDTE.CodeElement has [GetStartPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codeelement.getstartpoint.aspx) / GetEndPoint methods to get several relevant points. Given an EnvDTE.TextPoint you can create an EnvDTE.EditPoint (via [TextPoint.CreateEditPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.textpoint.createeditpoint.aspx)) and then call [EditPoint.GetText(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.editpoint.gettext.aspx)

For VS 2015 and higher and C#/VB.NET, you can use the [Compiler Platform (a.k.a. "Roslyn")](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/documentation) where the syntax and semantic models are exposed by the compiler